# How to get the points( Latitude and Longitude) between 2 points from google map in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, google-api

I am working in android studio , and the user will select 2 end points on the map, How can I get the points between these 2 end points? so I can compare some points i have with these points??

Also another Q. : I will save the location of the user,if I have points How to know the closest point to the user?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete answer of your problem.Google provide an Directions api for finding way points between two geo location see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/).

Go through [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/route-between-two-locations-with-waypoints-in-google-map-android-api-v2/) link. it has complete example with source code.

Hope you will get solution to your problem.